# Rails form trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So, I have something of an odd controller/view setup, editing a Product model object occurs in the listings controller/view. There is a long-winded explanation for why this is, but I digress. However, when I submit the form, I get the error `Couldn't find Product without an ID` . What gives? Strangely, when I look at the params sent with the request, the ID attribute is assigned to the 'format' key. ?!.

The controller code is very simple. Edit Action:

```
def edit
  @edit = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

Update Action:

```
def update
  @edit = Product.find(params[:id])

  if @edit.save
    redirect_to :url => listings_display_path
  end
end
```

Here is my form_for code:

```
<% form_for @edit, :url => (listings_update_path(@edit)) do |f| %>
```

Edit, the trace:

```
{"utf8"=>"âœ“",
"_method"=>"put",
"authenticity_token"=>"st17LW0S9uENaV8UBcxKUfRH67oo+r3TuFAxiPKMCEc=",
"product"=>{"brand"=>"test_brand",
"productname"=>"test_product",
"category"=>"test_category",
"regprice"=>"4",
"saleprice"=>"2",
"description"=>"description"},
"commit"=>"Submit",
"format"=>"21"}
```

Edit: routes.rb

```
resources :product do
  resources :promotions
  collection do
    get "replace"
  end
end

#listings
match 'listings/index' => 'listings#index'
match 'listings/display' => 'listings#display'
match 'listings/edit' => 'listings#edit'
match 'listings/update' => 'listings#update'
```

Edit: create action

```
def create

  @product = Product.new(params[:product])
  @product.user = current_user

  if @product.save
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end
end
```

Comment: what is `listings_update_path`? Where does it lead? Show THIS action code. Usually it is `update_litings_path` or even just `listings_path` with `PUT` method

Comment: That leads to the update action shown above. rake routes tells me it is 'listings_update_path'..

Comment: why don't you follow conventions in routing and naming?

Comment: There is a long reason.. It has to do with the fact that editing a lot of different models has to be done on the same page.

Comment: Show your trace (actually only importaint is `params` hash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= form_for @edit, :url => listings_path(@edit), :html => {:method => :put} do |f| %>
```

Comment: I get undefined method listings_path. Switching it out for listings_update_path gets me the original error, product cannot be found without id.

Comment: Can you see any `id` in your trace? I can't. Try this: `listings_update_path(:id => @edit.id)`

Comment: The id is assigned to the format key. I don't know why/how that happens

Comment: Because you didn't follow the convention :). So your code is messing up

Comment: Hmm, now the params change to the value of the url.. and it still can't find the id..

Comment: What happend? Show it. I speak Ruby better then English :)

Comment: {"url"=>"/listings/display"} is in the params now and the error is still 'Couldn't find Product without an ID'. How about if I were to assign @edit.id to a variable in the view, then put that variable into the session? Does that make sense?

Comment: have you tried this? `<%= form_for @edit, :url =>listings_update_path(:id => @edit.id) %>`

Comment: it can be troubles with your routes or anything else. Main problem here is architecture problem.

Comment: yes, that too replaces the 'params' with the :url. I also tried <%= form_for(@edit, listings_update_path(@edit)) do |f| %>, which directs me to the conventional path, product_path, even though I have listings_update_path and that is exactly how the docs say to write it.

Comment: I find it frustrating that rails does not allow me any flexibility. Is there a better way to allow the user to edit three models from one view? routes.rb is pretty large, I'll try to put only the relevant bits.

Comment: it is not about Rails at all ;)

Comment: mmmm `match 'listings/update' => 'listings#update', :as => :listings_update`

Comment: now its all going through the update action in the product controller. This is so confusing..

Comment: why do you think that they all going trhough the product controller? Because it redirects to product or you saw your logs?

Comment: It isn't following the listings_update_path instruction, but when I change it to :url => {:controller => 'listings', :action => 'update'} it goes through the listings controller. When I do that, the parameters contain the correct id, but I still get the no id error. I changed the update controller code to @edit = Product.find((params[:product])[:id]), BUT that somehow alters the params to be the url!!?? this makes no sense. I don't see how this could be my code causing this to happen.

Comment: `:url => {:controller => 'listings', :action => 'update', :id => @edit.id}`. Show your create action :)

Comment: I have edited to include the create action, but at the moment I feel that this is going to be too much effort to fix. I'm going to watch that rails cast you linked to, and perhaps try to find another approach. You have been enormously helpful, and Im going to go upvote all of your comments here. Thanks alot!

Comment: I SOLVED IT!!!!! Including the id in the routes, + putting ':as => listings_update', + :via => :put, + changing @edit.save to @edit.update_attributes!!!!!!!!!! SO happy!

Answer (score 1):

First, for an alternate approach to editing multiple records on a single view, try this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually

Second, this is unconventional but your whole approach is unconventional...

You can stick a [hidden field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field) in the form with the ID in it. Something like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field, :product, :id %>
```

Then check your params hash and the id will be in there. You should be able to access it in the controller using something similar to:

```
# untested
@edit = Product.find(params[:product][:id])
```

Off the top of my head I'm not sure how it will be stored in your params hash but it will be there and you'll be able to access it like any other hash attribute.

Good luck!

--EDIT--

Also, regarding your comment about lack of flexibility in Rails -- one thing I've learned is that Rails isn't inflexible, but it is highly optimized for particular conventions. The developers refer to this as being "highly opinionated" software, which means:

1. It can do just about anything you care to do it any way you want to do it, but...
2. There's almost always a "preferred" way which is better, faster (harder stronger lol).

You would save yourself tons of time and energy -- and probably have a lot of fun -- grabbing the [Beginning Rails 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224339) book. You could work through it in a weekend, and when you were done you would have a great primer on the "Rails Way" which would hopefully help you go from "I don't get why Rails doesn't do this or that" to "I get how Rails works and how easy it is to do what I want to do by following X pattern". That's what happened for me anyhow.

Again good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the routes that are for a single product instance to have the id:

```
match 'listings/index' => 'listings#index'
match 'listings/:id/display' => 'listings#display'
match 'listings/:id/edit' => 'listings#edit'
match 'listings/:id/update' => 'listings#update'
```

Comment: yes, I tried this at one stage, but to no avail. That is just the current state of my routes file. To show everything I have tried would take up an entire server's hard drive at StackOverflow

Comment: and add `:as` option. `match 'listings/:id/update' => 'listings#update', :as => listings_update` ...

Comment: when I do that, I don't get any error, but checking the database shows that the record was not updated. I tried adding :via => 'put' but then I get a route not found error.

Comment: Like fl00r said, you will want to add the `:as => listings_update` if you want to reference `listings_update_path` in your code. Without having the :id in the route, you won't get a route to match... so you need to start there. Then let us know what isn't working. Also, doesn't look like you have a route to the `listings#create` action, so you'll want to add that to.